# Trying to capitalize the first letter of each word in a user prompted sentence using a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def capitalize(word):
    s = str(input('Enter a sentence with multiple words: '))
    word = ' '.join(word[0].upper() + word[1:] for word in s.split())
print(capitalize(s))
```

I'm being told s is not defined
Any help in figuring this out is much appreciated

Comment: `s` is only defined inside the `capitalize` function. Move the `input()` line outside of that function and before the call to `capitalize`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
def capitalize(sentence):
    new_sentence = ' '.join([word[0].upper() + word[1:]
                           for word in sentence.split() ] )
    return(new_sentence)

s = "Enter a sentence with multiple words"
print(capitalize(s))
```

Output:

Enter A Sentence With Multiple Words

Yes, I used your input prompt as a test case.  :-)
I expect that you'll replace the assignment with the input command you want -- it's just that expecting an SO person to type your test case for you violates the MCVE idea.

Answer (score 0):

`s` isn't defined within the scope of the function. Try

```
def capitalize(word):
    word = ''.join(word[0].upper() + word[1:])
    return(word)

def capitalize_sentence(words):
    return(' '.join([capitalize(x) for x in words.split(' ')]))

s = input('Enter a sentence with multiple words: ')
print(capitalize_sentence(s))
```

Comment: I did print(captialize(s)) and it is only capitalizing the first word for me

Comment: @JordanSparks: right -- just as implied by your mis-named variable, `word`.

Comment: Yes, the capitalize function above just applies to a single word. The code above uses list comprehension to apply that function to EACH word individually, and joins the output with spaces

Comment: Looks like the other answer is this one copy-pasted into a single function that doesn't answer your initial question regarding "s is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the argument, `word` for the capitalize function. Since the function gets user input from `s = input(...)`, it's pointless to pass an argument to the function without it being used.

On the 3rd line, you could just return the capitalized string of `word` instead of assigning to it because of the scope of the function and the main program. [More about scopes](https://matthew-brett.github.io/teaching/global_scope.html).

Here's a fixed version of your program if you're not using the `.title()` method:

```
def capitalize():
    s = input('Enter a sentence with multiple words: ')
    return ' '.join(word[0].upper() + word[1:] for word in s.split())

print(capitalize())
```

There's a simpler way to do this -- use the built-in `.title()` method:

```
def capitalize():
    s = input('Enter a sentence with multiple words: ')
    return s.title()
```

And another way you can acheive a capitalized string without a function, which is the most straightforward way in my opinion:

```
s = input('Enter a sentence with multiple words: ').title()
```